# hosting web site with home U-verse

Tags: webserver

I recently had to be moved from ATT DSL to U-verse. At home I host a small non-commercial website with a domain name registered, listening on port 80.  I can access the website if signed in to my employer's VPN at home, but not from any machine in my home network.  This worked for a few days after switching, but then suddenly stopped working.

Any idea what's going on and if it can be fixed?

Since I can get to it from VPN, I assume folks outside of U-verse can see it.  How about folks with U-verse as their ISP?  The web site is http://www.jtlanguage.com.

Note that I didn't see any restrictions for doing this in the TOS, but I was still a little afraid to ask.

Thanks.

-John

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you're seeing a problem with your edge router / NAT device being unable to do [hairpin NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning). Your web site is resolving to a public IP address and, when accessed from the LAN network behind your NAT device the device is unable to correctly route that traffic back to the LAN.

You probably don't run your own DNS server on your LAN so the simple "fix" isn't going to work for you. (Were this a professional sysadmin inquiry, I'd advise you to put an "A" record in your on-LAN DNS server for your website's public DNS name resolving to its LAN IP address.) Given that you don't likely have a DNS server on-LAN I don't think there's an easy fix for you.

Comment: An ugly fix if the above is the issue might be to edit the HOSTS file on every workstation to have jtlanguage.com point to the internal IP of the server and then make sure the webserver is accepting connections on the LAN interface.